# SQL Concatenate multiple rows after Case statement inside LEFT JOIN statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have separate tables

```
Table1:
| AppID        | Desc | 
|--------------|------|
| 1            | App1 |
| 2            | App2 |

Table2:
| CollateralID | Type  | AppID |
|--------------|-------|-------|
| 1            | Home  | 1     |
| 2            | Condo | 1     |
| 3            | Condo | 2     |

Table3:
| TitleID | Address1 | Address2 | Address3 | CollateralID  |
|---------|----------|----------|----------|---------------|
| 1       | Add1a    | Add2a    | Add3a    |   1           |
| 2       | Add1b    | Add2b    | Null     |   2           |
| 3       | Add1c    | Add2c    | Null     |   3           |


Desired Results:
| AppID  | Desc | Type        | Complete Address |
|--------|------|-------------|------------------|
| 1      | App1 | Home; Condo | Add1a + Add2a + Add3a; Add1b + Add2b |
| 2      | App2 | Condo       | Add1c + Add2c |
```

So far, this is only what I got

```
SELECT  app.AppID                       AS AppID,
        app.Desc                        AS Desc,
        details.type                    AS Type,
        details.compadd                 AS "Complete Address"

FROM    Table1    app
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   tab2.AppID,
                    tab2.Type, 
                    
                    CASE WHEN tab2.Type = 'HOME' 
                         THEN tab3.Address1 || ' ' || tab3.Address2 || ' ' || tab3.Address3

                         WHEN tab2.Type = 'CONDO' 
                         THEN tab3.Address1 || ' ' || tab3.Address2 

                    END AS compadd      
            
            FROM  Table2 tab2 
            JOIN  Table3 tab3 ON tab2.CollateralID = tab3.CollateralID
            ) details ON app.AppdID = tab2.AppID
```

WHAT I AM MISSING and cannot understand how to apply:

How can I concatenate the Type and the Complete Address for an AppID as shown above?

Appreciate the help in advanced. Let me know if it isn't clear. Thank you!

Comment: I still need help with this, pleaseee

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need a `subquery` to achieve what you need.
Second, use `upper()` function to make sure you have the exact match

```
select app.AppID as AppID
    , app.Desc as "Desc"
    , tab2.type as "Type"
    , case 
        when upper(tab2.Type) = 'HOME'  
            then tab3.Address1 || ' ' ||  tab3.Address2 ||  ' ' ||  tab3.Address3
        when upper(tab2.Type) = 'CONDO'
            then tab3.Address1 ||  ' ' ||  tab3.Address2 end as "Complete Address"
from Table1 app
left join Table2 tab2 on tab2.AppID = app.AppID
left join Table3 tab3 on tab3.CollateralID = tab2.CollateralID
```

Comment: I tried to apply this code however I encounter an error: 

ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments
00909. 00000 -  "invalid number of arguments"
*Cause:    
*Action:

this is pointing to the "Then" clause. pls help

Comment: @sellavsert, try now

Comment: still the same. :( my actual code has more address.. is there a limit for concat function? here is my case statement in my actual code:

Comment: `code`
CASE WHEN upper(coll.lac_collateral_type_c) = 'CONDO'  THEN CONCAT(title.unit_no, ' ', title.park_tit_solt_no, ' ', title.village, ' ', title.street, ' ', title.district, ' ', title.town_city, ' ', title.province)

WHEN upper(coll.lac_collateral_type_c) IN ('HOME', 'AUTO')  THEN CONCAT(title.lot_no, ' ', title.blockno, ' ', title.street, ' ', oth.village, ' ', title.district, ' ', title.town_city, ' ', title.province) 

END AS "Collateral Address"

`code`

Comment: the "error at line" is pointing to my line of "THEN CONCAT()....

Comment: yes, it has limit, use || operator instead

Comment: Hi, I apologize but I think my question was misunderstood. upon application of your code, I get multiple rows for an AppID because I have multiple values in Tab3 tagged to the AppID.. what i wanted to get is that I will be able to join all the Tab3 values tagged to an AppID to one cell and is only separated by ";". sample: Address1ofAppID1; Address2ofAppID1

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GROUP BY clause with STRING_AGG function. like below

```
SELECT  app.AppID AS AppID, app.Desc AS Desc, details.type AS Type, details.compadd AS "Complete Address"
FROM    Table1    app
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT   tab2.AppID, STRING_AGG(tab2.Type,';') Type, 
STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN tab2.Type = 'HOME' 
THEN tab3.Address1 || ' ' || tab3.Address2 || ' ' || tab3.Address3
WHEN tab2.Type = 'CONDO' 
THEN tab3.Address1 || ' ' || tab3.Address2 
END,';') AS compadd      
FROM  Table2 tab2 
JOIN  Table3 tab3 ON tab2.CollateralID = tab3.CollateralID
Group By tab2.AppID
) details ON app.AppdID = details.AppID
```

Comment: Hi appreciate the response. however, this is not working with SQL Developer.. may i know what is the alternative for string_agg for sql developer?

Comment: What version of SQL you are using? STRING_Agg was first introduced in the first update of SQL SERVER 2017.

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer (3.2.10.09)

Comment: I am receiving the error: ORA-00904: "STRING_AGG": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: For Oracle, Use LISTAGG function. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030

Comment: LISTAGG(CASE WHEN tab2.Type = 'HOME' 
THEN tab3.Address1 || ' ' || tab3.Address2 || ' ' || tab3.Address3
WHEN tab2.Type = 'CONDO' 
THEN tab3.Address1 || ' ' || tab3.Address2 
,';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY tab2.AppID) AS compadd

my code above does not work.. :( help pls...